# Assigning a variable from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, protocols

I have a `UIView` with a `UIButton` created in 1 class: "`viewClass`". In my `mainVC` class, I called `viewClas` and I needed to call a method in `mainVc` when the `button` is selected, so I created a `protocol`. (I hope that was clear.)

Here's how I set up the `protocol` and `delegate`:

**`viewClass.h`**

```
@protocol ViewClassDelegate

-(void)buttonWasClicked;

@end

...
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ViewClassDelegate> delegate;
```

**`viewClass.m`**

```
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitButtonTapped) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)submitButtonTapped {
    [self.delegate buttonWasClicked];
}
```

**`mainVC.m`**

```
// Imported and called the delegate in mainVC.h. Then in .m I set the delegate

-(void)buttonWasClicked {
    // Perform some action
}
```

Is there a way to pass an `NSString` to `buttonWasClicked`? I don't mean like this:

```
- (void)buttonWasClicked:(NSString *)myString
```

because `myString` has no value unless I assign it in `mainVC` method. I want to assign it in `submitButtonTapped` (which is in `myView.m`).

Basically, I want something like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

In that method, it knows what `textField` is without me defining it when I use that method.

Hope this is clear. If someone can explain it better, feel free to edit it. If you need more clarification, please ask in the comments.

Comment: From where do you want to pass a `NSString` to where?

Comment: From `myView` to `mainVC` ?

Comment: Yes. From `myView` to `mainVC` through the method `buttonWasClicked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**viewClass.h**

```
@protocol ViewClassDelegate

-(void)buttonWasClicked:(NSString *)aString;

@end
```

**viewClass.m**

```
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitButtonTapped) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)submitButtonTapped {
    [self.delegate buttonWasClicked:@"this is a string"];
}
```

**mainVC.m**

```
// Imported and called the delegate in mainVC.h. Then in .m I set the delegate

-(void)buttonWasClicked:(NSString *)aString {
    // aString = this is a string 
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Can't believe it was that easy!! Thanks!! Is there a name to that?

Comment: :) not sure there are any special terms for this. But this is just Delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
@protocol ViewClassDelegate

-(void)buttonWasClicked:(NSString*)value;

@end

...
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewClassDelegate> delegate;

[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitButtonTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)submitButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
    [self.delegate buttonWasClicked:stringToSendWhereverHasBeenDefined];
}

...

-(void)buttonWasClicked:(NSString*)value {
    // Perform some action
}
```

Comment: Instead of the button, I want to pass an already defined string

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please let me know if I am missing any detail